# analysis integral question from 0 to 1 inequality

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

> When $f$ and $g$ being positive satisfy $f(x)g(x) \ge 1$ for every $x$ on $[0,1]$, then 
>   $$\int_0^1 f(x) dx  \int_0^1 g(x) dx \ge 1$$

I can show this when $f$ and $g$ are monotone, but general positive $g$ and positive $f$, I don't know??

Thank you for your time...

Comment: One way is to apply Holder's inequality to $\sqrt{fg}$.

Comment: And I guess the other function is $h==1$ over $[0,1]$?

Comment: It is not true in general: try $f(x)=g(x)=-2$ when $x \lt \frac12$ and $f(x)=g(x)=+2$ when $x \ge \frac12$.  But it is true if both are positive on this interval

Comment: How do you show it when they are positive ? Thank you..

Comment: @Salih Ucan: You can use Holder's inequality: use the functions $(fg)^{1/2}$ and $1$ , and apply Holder's inequality, using the fact that both functions are square-integrable, i.e., both ${fg}^{1/2}$ and $1$ are in $L^2[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to apply [Hölder's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) to $\sqrt{fg}$, since we then find that

\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 \sqrt{fg} dx &= \|\sqrt{fg}\|_1 \\
&\le \|\sqrt{f}\|_2 \|\sqrt g\|_2 \\
&= \left(\int_0^1 f(x) dx\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_0^1 g(x) dx\right)^{1/2}
\end{align*}

Now since we have $\sqrt{fg} dx \ge 1$ almost everywhere, monotonicity of the integral leads to $1 \le \int_0^1 \sqrt{fg}$; the final result follows by squaring.